# Что собой представляет кольцевой стек и где он используется?

Tags: терминология, стек

Что собой представляет кольцевой стек и где он используется?

Answer (score 2):

Это обычный стек, в котором первый и последний элементы массива совпадают - то есть вершина и основание стека закольцованы.

Используется для буферизации потока данных.

Ссылка на хорошую статью: [Circular buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer)

Comment: @Barmaley, и все-таки (с циклическим **буфером** все очевидно) кто и когда использует *циклический****стек*****?**